# Script Does not work when run by a PyQt4 button

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to have mouse clicks recorded at the clicked x and y location. The script works fine on its own but when linked to a PyQt4 button it freezes the the GUI. And no error is generated. How can I have this script run through a GUI?

enter code here :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import win32api
import time
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.run_script)            

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()

    def run_script(self):
```

mousecapturesequence(win32api.GetKeyState(0x01),win32api.GetKeyState(0x02))

```
    class POINT(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("x", c_long), ("y", c_long)]

    def queryMousePosition(self):
        pt = POINT()
        windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
        return { "x": pt.x, "y": pt.y}

    def mousecapturesequence(self,state_left,state_right):
        x = 1
        while (x < 3):
            a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
            if a != state_left:  # Button state changed
                state_left = a
                print(a)
                if a < 0:
                    print('Left Button Pressed')
                    pos = self.queryMousePosition()
                    print(pos)
                    x = x + 1
                else:
                    print('Left Button Released')

            time.sleep(0.001)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: don't create an event polling loop in your callback. That freezes the GUI, of course.